# How do I prove that there exists a such measure?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $(\Omega,\mathscr{F},P)$ be a probability space and $f:\Omega\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ be a measurable function such that $\int_\Omega ||f|| dP < \infty$.

Let $\{e_1,...,e_n\}$ be the standard ordered basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Then, how do I prove that there exists a measure $\mu:\mathscr{B}_\mathbb{R^n}\otimes \mathscr{B}_\mathbb{R^n} \rightarrow [0,\infty]$ such that $\mu(A\times B)=\int_{\Omega} (\mathbb{1}_B\circ f)\cdot (\sum_{k=1}^n \mathbb{1}_{A}(e_k) f_k) dP$?

Define $S:=\{A\times B:A,B\in \mathscr{B}_\mathbb{R^n}\}$.

I tried to show that $\mu$ is a premeasure on $S$ and then apply the Caratheodory extension theorem to acquire the measure. However, I am stuck at proving that $\mu$ is a premeasure on $S$.. (I cannot show the $\sigma$-additivity)

How do I show the existence of $\mu$?

Comment: What are $c_k$ and $f_k$?

Comment: @amsmath Where is $c_k$? $f_k$ means the $k$-th coordinate of $f$.

Comment: So first you have to show that the expression for $\mu(A \times B) = \int_\Omega ... dP$ is well defined i.e. that the $...$ is measurable. Can you show  this?

Comment: Of course that's measurable. Define $L:=\mathbb{1}_B \cdot (\sum_{k=1}^n \mathbb{1}_A (e_k) \pi_k)$, which is obviously measurable. ($\pi_k$'a are coordinate maps). Note that the integrand is $L\circ f$.

Comment: Ok, the expression for $\mu$ is then well defined. What problem are you having showing countable additivity , for example? I want to see your attempt.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг Please check my answer below.

Comment: Thank you! I will have a look, just having dinner!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure whether my argument is correct, so someone please check if it is correct.

Define $a(w,A):=(\mathbb{1}_{B}\circ f)(w)$ and $b(w,B):=\sum_{k=1}^n \mathbb{1}_A(e_k)f_k(w)$, for all $w\in \Omega$ and $A,B\in\mathscr{B}_\mathbb{R^n}$.

Let $\{A_i\times B_i\}_{i\in \mathbb{N}}$ be a mutually disjoint sequence in $S$ such that $\bigcup (A_i\times B_i) \in S$. Hence, we can write it as $A'\times B'=\bigcup (A_i\times B_i)$

Fix $w\in \Omega$.

Note that $a(w,\cdot)$ and $b(w,\cdot)$ are finite measures. Let $c$ be their product measure.

Then $$a(w,A')b(w,B')=c(A'\times B')=\sum c(A_i\times B_i)=\sum a(w,A_i)b(w,B_i)$$.

And this holds for all $w$.

Thus, $$\mu(A'\times B')=\int a(w,A')b(w,B') dP(w)= \int \sum a(w,A_i)b(w,B_i) dP(w) = \sum \int a(w,A_i)b(w,B_i) dP(w)= \sum \mu(A_i\times B_i)$$.

Hence, we get the $\sigma$-additivity of $\mu$.

Comment: I have a question : for caratheodory extension theorem you require a ring of subsets to proceed. However, the measure $\mu$ is not defined for sets which are generated by the set $S$, and $S$ itself is not a ring, so I see incompleteness in the question. However, your explanation is correct.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг $S$ is a semi-ring. And Caratheodory extension theorem can be applied to semi-rings.

Comment: Ah, then your argument is correct, it seems. How do you justify the exchange of the integral and the summation on the last line? If you are sure on that, then I think you are fine.

Comment: That's true by monotone convergence theorem. Thank you for checking it!

Comment: Exactly : basically we can always exchange if the integrand is positive. You are welcome, you can accept your own answer.